# Map two table to singe arraylist object using jdbc connection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, collections, arraylist

I have two table i.e SALE and SALEPRODUCT(there is one to many relationship between both table(.
SALE table contain detail of individual sale and SALEPRODUCT contain all the product detail related to that sale.
I have fetch all the sale and their respective products detail.
I hv 2 classes sale and saleProduct. Both classes having their variable and properties for those variable.
I want to fetch data like below example.

```
 List<Data> sale= new ArrayList<Data>();
      List<SubData> saleProduct= new ArrayList<SubData>();
      subData.add(new saleProduct(2011, 0, 10, 2));
      subData.add(new saleProduct(2011, 0, 15, 3));
      data.add(new Data("DVD", 5, new BigDecimal(30), subData));
      saleProduct= new ArrayList<SubData>();
      subData.add(new saleProduct(2011, 0, 11, 1);
      subData.add(new saleProduct(2011, 0, 12, 3);
      subData.add(new saleProduct(2011, 0, 16, 4));
      data.add(new Data("Book", 8, new BigDecimal(11), subData));
      saleProduct= new ArrayList<SubData>();
      subData.add(new saleProduct(2011, 0, 9, 1));
      subData.add(new saleProduct(2011, 0, 18, 1));
      data.add(new Data("PDA", 2, new BigDecimal(15), subData));
```

Its dummy a hard coded data but i want data from database(from two table).
How we can fetch data from those two table and create single List or collection or ArrayList object.

Comment: Do an inner join fetch in SQL and map it to your objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute an SQL as you are not using any ORM framework this is the way I could think of,

```
SELECT *
FROM SALES s,
     SALEPRODUCT sp 
WHERE s.id=sp.id;
```

Here I have assumed that id is the 
common column in both of the tables (for maintaining relationship). Then you will get a list containing all the necessary results, fetch each result create your class object from it and then add it to a collection or list.

Sample code:-

```
public class MyCustomEntity {
  // Here add all the attributes that you get from your query
  // Add getters and setters for all those attributes.
}
```

Now when you obtain your result, you create a new instance of this MyCustomEntity class.

```
while(some condition) {

MyCustomEntity mce = new MyCustomEntity();
mce.setXXX(pass your parameter from result here);
Set<MyCustomEntity> mySet = new HashSet<MyCustomEntity>();
mySet.add(mce);

}
```

Thus create your collection.

Comment: Query is not my problem. how to store this result into object?

Comment: If you are getting result which contains all these parameters then just simply apply setter methods on newly created object and then add it to the list/collection you want.

Comment: If my answer is suitable for you please accept it and close the question.